# PHP / SQL - Multiply primary keys (Update on duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grid_users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `times_played` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `won_total` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `won_1` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Did user win prize 1? If yes, show badge',
  `won_1_time` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `won_2` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `won_2_time` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `won_3` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `won_3_time` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `last_update` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see, "`userid`" is set to be the primary key.

Although I want PHP to check whether **two** of the columns exists, and if they do -> update:

```
if($type == "1"){
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO grid_users (type) 
            VALUES ('1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE won_total=won_total+'1';");

            }elseif($type == "2"){
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO grid_users (type) 
            VALUES ('2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE won_total=won_total+'1';");

            }
try {
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Although now, as there is only one primary key it checks for (Userid), it will simply just update the first record in the database no matter what `$type` is being set to.

Comment: `UNIQUE KEY (\`userid\`,\`type\`)`

Comment: UPDATE grid_users SET UNIQUE KEY (`userid`,`type`) doesn't work..

Comment: No, `UNIQUE KEY` has to be used in your table creation -> `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`grid_users\` ( ...your columns..., PRIMARY KEY (\`userid\`), UNIQUE KEY (\`userid\`,\`type\`) ...` or use `ALTER TABLE \`grid_users\` ADD UNIQUE KEY (\`userid\`,\`type\`)`

Comment: Although it will only work if you also specify the other column, so that it knows if there is a duplicate -> `INSERT INTO grid_users (userid,type) VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I don't understand why you are using an `insert` for this.  Why not just do:

```
update grid_users
    set won_total = won_total + 1
    where type = 1;
```

Comment: Because there is a new entry for each new user (userid)

Comment: @oliverbj . . . You are not passing in the `userid` to the insert, so it will be set to `NULL` and the `insert` will fail.